# Is every locally compact group/ homogeneous space locally homeomorphic to the Cantor set or an n-torus?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Two topological spaces $ X $ and $ X' $ are locally homeomorphic if for any $ p \in X $ and $ p' \in X' $ there exists a homeomorphism from a neighborhood of $ p $ to a neighborhood of $ p' $.

Is every locally compact Hausdorff group locally homeomorphic to exactly one of the following?

i)  Cantor set

ii) $ T^n $, where $ T $ is the circle and $ n $ is a cardinal

(I considered adding solenoid to this list but solenoids are not locally connected so I think they might be locally homeomorphic to the Cantor set. On the other hand, the Cantor set is locally totally disconnected which is stronger than just failing to be locally connected.)

A topological space is called homogeneous if it is locally homeomorphic to itself. Is every (locally compact Hausdorff) homogeneous space locally homeomorphic to exactly one of the above listed spaces?

Comment: I think, if you also assume metrizable (or 1st countable) then, locally, each locally compact group is homeomorphic to the Cantor set or a singleton, times $R^n$ (for some $n$). This is likely to be in the book by Montgomery and Zippin.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Any result like that would need much stronger hypotheses than just metrizability.  For instance, a countably infinite product of circles is metrizable.

Comment: @EricWofsey :Right, one needs to assume finite dimensional.

Comment: Nice question by Moishe and Eric (whether finite-dimensional second metrizable $G$ is locally homeomorphic to Euclidian $\times$ Cantor). A starting point for such questions is the abelian case, which seems both doable and nontrivial in such a case. One can easily reduce to the case of a (finite-dimensional metrizable) compact abelian group. For instance it works for such a non-obvious case as the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbf{Q}$, using the embedding of the latter into adeles as cocompact lattice.

Comment: @Ycor now I want to know if every topological group with finite topological dimension is locally homeomorphic to product of point or cantor set with Euclidean space. Should I ask a new question or change this one? Also does that mean the solenoid does not have finite topological dimension?

Comment: Of course you shouldn't change this one, which has an accepted answer. (Solenoid is locally homeo to $\mathbf{R}\times\text{(Cantor)}$. Also you should require metrizable.)

Comment: @YCor: Alex Ravsky found a reference to this in the compact case. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567423/finite-dimensional-group-is-locally-a-manifold-or-product-with-a-cantor-set

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks; the general case should follow easily from the compact case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is horribly false.  Indeed, a solenoid is a counterexample, since it is neither locally connected nor locally totally disconnected.  For a simpler example of the same phenomenon, you could take a group like $\mathbb{R}\times G^\mathbb{N}$ where $G$ is a nontrivial finite group.

Another example is $G^I$ where $G$ is a nontrivial finite group and $I$ is uncountable; this is totally disconnected but not first-countable so it is not locally homeomorphic to the Cantor set.  Or, you could take $G=S^3$ (or actually any compact connected Lie group that is not a torus would do) and consider $G^I$ for an infinite set $I$.  This is not locally homeomorphic to $T^n$ for any $n$ since $T^n$ has a local neighborhood base of subsets whose third homotopy group vanishes but $G^I$ does not.

It seems extremely unlikely to me that there is any nice classification of the local homeomorphism types of locally compact groups in full generality.

Comment: Can you say more about the argument with local base where third homotopy group vanishes? That sounds really interesting!

Comment: It's pretty trivial.  $T^n$ has a local base consisting of products of intervals and circles, all of which have vanishing $\pi_3$.  On the other hand any nonempty basic open set in $G^I$ is a product of factors which are $G$ on all but finitely many coordinates and so has nontrivial $\pi_3$ (and by considering the projection onto that coordinate, the same must be true of any larger open set).

Comment: Morally, the point is that since the product topology only lets you constrain finitely many factors at a time, open sets in $T^n$ have to look a lot like $T^{n-m}$ for some finite $m$ and similarly for $G^I$.  Intuitively, it should not be surprising that these cannot be homeomorphic.  The argument with $\pi_3$ is just a way to prove it rigorously.