# finite dimensional group is locally a manifold or product with a cantor set

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Is it the case that every compact topological group with finite topological dimension is locally homeomoprhic to a cantor set or $ \mathbb{R}^n $ or a product of a cantor set with  $ \mathbb{R}^n $?

This is a follow up to:

[Is every locally compact group/ homogeneous space locally homeomorphic to the Cantor set or an n-torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536753/is-every-locally-compact-group-homogeneous-space-locally-homeomorphic-to-the-ca)

Comment: This is not the case for finite discrete groups.

Comment: I just opened “Continuous groups” by Pontrjagin at a random page and read the following theorem. A compact locally connected second countable topological group $X$ is a direct sum of a finite group and a finitely of countably many subgroups, isomorphic to $\Bbb T$ (one-dimensional torus); that is $X$ is $\Bbb T^rF$, where $r$ is countable.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky I consider a discrete group to be locally $ \mathbb{R}^0 $ and thus it is true for discrete groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All topological spaces considered below are supposed to be Hausdorff.

**Theorem.** ([Pon, Th. 69]) Each compact group $G$ of finite dimension $r$ locally splits in a direct product of an $r$-dimensional Lie group $L$ and a zero-dimensional closed normal subgroup $N$ of $G$. More precisely, the group $G$ contains a subset $L$, homeomorphic to an open $r$-dimensional cube and zero-dimensional normal subgroup $N$ such that
a)  Each element of $l\in L$ commutes with each element $n\in N$;
b) A set $V=LN$ is a neighborhood of the identity of $G$;
c) Each element $v\in V$ has a unique representation $v=ln$, where $l\in L$, $n\in N$, and both $l$ and $n$ are continuous functions of $v$;
d) If $l_1$ and $l_2$ are elements of $L$ such that $l_1l_2\in V$ then $l_1l_2\in L$, so $L$ is a local group with respect to the multiplication of $G$;
e) The local group $L$ is a Lie group.
The above directly implies that $G/N$ is a local Lie group. It turns out that we can put as $N$ any zero-dimensional closed normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a Lie group.

Concerning locally compact groups, I can tell on Abelian case.  According to [Pon], a topological group $G$ is of *compact origin* if it has a compact neighborhood of the identity $V$ such that $G$ is its smallest  subgroup containing $V$. It is easy to check that for each compact neighborhood $V$ of a locally compact group $G$, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} V^n$ is an *open* subgroup of compact origin of $G$. I guess (I didn’t find a definition in [DPS]) that locally compact groups of compact origin are exactly locally compact compactly generated groups in sense of [DPS]. By Theorem 3.3.1 from [DPS], every compactly generated locally compact Abelian group is isomorphic to a product $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb Z^m\times C$, where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers and $C$ is a compact Abelian group. Also by Theorem 51 and Example 69 from [Pon], an Abelian group $G$ of  compact origin splits into a direct sum of a compact group and some number of copies of groups $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$, and in this decomposition the compact summand is defined uniquely as the largest compact subgroup of $G$. Also, by [Theorem  3.3.10, DPS], each locally compact Abelian group has a closed subgroup $H$ containing an open compact subgroup of $G$ such that $G\cong \Bbb R^n\times H$ for some non-negative integer $n$ (I guess “$\cong$” means “is isomorphic to”).  The chapter on locally compact Abelian groups of [Pon] is finished by a claim that a locally compact locally connected finitely-dimensional second countable Abelian topological group is a Lie group. I guess [Pon] book does not considers a general case of non-Abelian locally compact groups, because the following chapters of [Pon] are devoted to the notion of a Lie group, structure of compact topological groups, locally isomorphic groups, Lie groups and algebras, and structure of compact Lie groups.

*References*

[DPS] Dikran N. Dikranjan, Ivan R. Prodanov, Luchezar N. Stoyanov. *Topological Groups*, Marcel Dekker, New-York, 1990.

[Pon] Lev Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).

Comment: How do totally disconnected groups like pro finite and p adic Lie groups fit into this? Would they be the N part? Do they have topological dimension 0 despite being non discrete? Or do they not have finite topological dimension at all?

Comment: @Ianteixeira By a totally disconnected space I understood a space with one-point quasi-components. Since in a compact space the component of a point coincides with its quasi-component (see, for instance, Engelking’s “General topology”, 2nd edn., Theorem 6.1.23). So a totally disconnected compact space is hereditarily disconnected and it is zero-dimensional by Theorem 6.2.9 from the same book.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Very nice! Do you know about locally compact finite-dimensional case?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the story in the case of general (Hausdorff) locally compact finite dimensional groups $G$. In section 4.9.3 of

*Montgomery, Deane; Zippin, Leo*, Topological transformation groups, Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 978-0-486-82449-9). xi, 289 p. (2018). [ZBL1418.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1418.57024).

it is proven that there exists a local (continuous) isomorphism of $G$ to the product of a compact totally disconnected group and a local Lie group.